# Issue with flipping sprite in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I was following a youtube guide on scripting a 2D platformer, I have gotten to the point now where I am trying to add a flip to the sprite when I turn to go in the opposite direction.

I have added a code and now this is constantly flipping left to right. If I understand correctly its probably because I am constantly applying > 0.1f when moving resulting in the function to continuously run but honestly I am lost so any help would be appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof (Controller2D))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public float jumpHeight = 4;
public float timeToJumpApex = .4f;
float accelerationTimeAirbourne = .2f;
float acceleratinTimeGrounded =.1f;
public float moveSpeed = 6;

float jumpVelocity;
float gravity;
Vector3 velocity;
float velocityXSmoothing; 

Controller2D controller;    

void Start(){
    controller = GetComponent<Controller2D>();
    gravity = -(2 * jumpHeight) / Mathf.Pow (timeToJumpApex, 2);
    jumpVelocity = Mathf.Abs(gravity) * timeToJumpApex;     
    print ("gravity: " + gravity + " Jump Velocity: " + jumpVelocity);
}

void Update(){

    if (controller.collisions.above || controller.collisions.above) {
        velocity.y = 0;
    }

    Vector2 input = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"), 
Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"));

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && controller.collisions.below) {
        velocity.y = jumpVelocity;
    }

    float targetVelocityX = input.x * moveSpeed;
    velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, targetVelocityX, ref 
velocityXSmoothing, (controller.collisions.below)?
acceleratinTimeGrounded:accelerationTimeAirbourne);
    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

void FixedUpdate(){

if ((Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1f && this.transform.localScale.x != 1) 
|| (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < -0.1f && this.transform.localScale.x != 
-1))
{
flip();
}

}

void flip()
{
     this.transform.localScale = new Vector3(this.transform.localScale.x * 
  -1, 
    this.transform.localScale.y, this.transform.localScale.z);
}



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here

```
void FixedUpdate(){
if ((Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1f && this.transform.localScale.x != 1)|| (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < -0.1f && this.transform.localScale.x != 
-1)){
        flip();
    }
}
```

After you flip, the condition still evaluates to true. You will need a boolean `hasflipped` to check if you have already flipped, and if you have don't flip again :)

Fixed update is causing this check to happen once per frame, so you're going to get a bunch of flickering as your sprite flips every frame, unless you specify only to flip once

Comment: Would you be so kind to give me an example script? I understand what you mean however applying is difficult :)

Comment: use `Input.GetKeyDown("/*the key*/")` instead :) That way you can call it in the `FixedUpdate()` function and it will only trigger once. Hope this helps!